Prints printing to the right of the bed after the firmware change
I changed to "mriscoc firmware" on my Creality Ender 3 V2 Neo and everything went pretty smooth. The printer itself works good, mesh is working good, I even went the length to measure the offsets and everything instead of copying it from the internet. But I probably can't figure out how to project those changes into Cura, cause my prints come right out of the bed. for some reason, like the first test line is fine, but then it starts to print to the right and out of the printable bed area.
I tried to copy the settings into Cura, to be identical to the printer. Where did I go wrong?


So I kinda presume I have some kind of mismatch?

Can you add a photo of a print like this parametric square with cross hair? How much off is it? About 4 cm?

The configuration defines no distance between the X-min endstop #define X_MIN_POS 0 and the print origin.
So, if you define the X offset in Cura to be at -38.3 mm, Cura will assume that you need to travel that distance to the right, hence all the prints are offset to the right.
You either define the offsets in the firmware or in the slicer, if you have to! The Ender has X=0 at the X min endstop, so no offset is needed at all, not in the slicer and not in the firmware.
So, please set the "Nozzle X offset" and "Nozzle Y offset" to 0.
You can easily check it you are printing exactly in the center using e.g. this parametric square with cross hair.
